# How to expose a Github Docker container action's ports to be accessible to the rest of the workflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to create a GitHub Action that initializes the [ChromaDB](https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma) server which serves in port `8000` and exposes that to the rest of the workflow.

Currently to initialize the server you simply run `docker-compose up -d` and that starts up the server. That works both locally and in a github action workflow.

```yaml
name: Docker Compose Workflow

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build and run Docker Compose
      run: |
        docker-compose up -d

    - name: Wait for server to be ready
      run: |
        while ! curl -s http://localhost:8000 > /dev/null; do
          echo "Waiting for server..."
          sleep 5
        done

    - name: Verify server is running
      run: |
        curl http://localhost:8000
```

The issue lies when I refactor it, so that running the server can be its own GitHub Action. The refactor involves creating the `action.yml` file like so:

```yaml
name: 'ChromaDB'
description: 'Instantiates a chroma database server'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'docker/compose:1.29.2'
  entrypoint: docker-compose
  args:
    - up
    - -d
```

and then replace the `"Build and run Docker Compose"` with running the local action instead. Transforming the workflow into this:

```yaml
name: Docker Compose Workflow

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build and run Docker Compose
      uses: ./

    - name: Wait for server to be ready
      run: |
        while ! curl -s http://localhost:8000 > /dev/null; do
          echo "Waiting for server..."
          sleep 5
        done

    - name: Verify server is running
      run: |
        curl http://localhost:8000
```

This does not work, the wait for server to be ready runs endlessly implying that server at port `8000` is never started.

How could I create the action that runs the server and exposes the server at port `8000` for the rest of the workflow?

Note:
GPT-4 suggested that the Docker container action runs as a self hosted environment.
[chat](https://chat.openai.com/share/29e51712-623b-4af5-a14d-d7f3d06bf3dc)

> The issue arises because the localhost in your Docker container
> (running the Docker Compose) is not the same as the localhost of the
> runner environment (which is the host of your Docker container). Thus,
> when your workflow tries to access localhost:8000 after your Docker
> container has started the services, it's trying to access
> localhost:8000 of the runner environment and not of the Docker
> container, where your services are actually running.

Thanks in advance!

Logs for "Build and run docker compose" step (highlights):

> /usr/bin/docker run --name dockercompose1292_63ab6b --label ed866e
> --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e
> "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e
> "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e
> "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e
> "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e
> "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e
> "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e
> "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e
> "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE"
> -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e
> "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e
> "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e
> "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e
> "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e
> "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true --entrypoint
> "docker-compose" -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v
> "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v
> "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v
> "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands"
> -v "/home/runner/work/chroma/chroma":"/github/workspace" docker/compose:1.29.2  "up" "-d" Unable to find image
> 'docker/compose:1.29.2' locally
> 1.29.2: Pulling from docker/compose ... Get:92 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libldap-common all
> 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1 [95.8 kB] Get:93 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsasl2-modules amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1
> [104 kB] Get:94 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64
> manpages-dev all 5.10-1 [2309 kB] debconf: delaying package
> configuration, since apt-utils is not installed Fetched 86.7 MB in 1s
> (113 MB/s) Selecting previously unselected package perl-modules-5.32.
> ... Successfully installed anyio-3.7.0 backoff-2.2.1 certifi-2023.5.7
> charset-normalizer-2.1.1 click-8.1.3 clickhouse-connect-0.5.7
> coloredlogs-15.0.1 duckdb-0.7.1 exceptiongroup-1.1.1 fastapi-0.85.1
> flatbuffers-23.5.26 h11-0.14.0 hnswlib-0.7.0 httptools-0.5.0
> humanfriendly-10.0 idna-3.4 lz4-4.3.2 monotonic-1.6 mpmath-1.3.0
> numpy-1.21.6 onnxruntime-1.14.1 overrides-7.3.1 packaging-23.1
> pandas-1.3.5 posthog-2.4.0 protobuf-4.23.2 pulsar-client-3.1.0
> pydantic-1.9.0 pypika-0.48.9 python-dateutil-2.8.2 python-dotenv-1.0.0
> pytz-2023.3 pyyaml-6.0 requests-2.28.1 six-1.16.0 sniffio-1.3.0
> starlette-0.20.4 sympy-1.12 tokenizers-0.13.2 tqdm-4.65.0
> typing_extensions-4.5.0 urllib3-1.26.16 uvicorn-0.18.3 uvloop-0.17.0
> watchfiles-0.19.0 websockets-11.0.3 zstandard-0.21.0 WARNING: Running
> pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and
> conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is
> recommended to use a virtual environment instead:
> https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
>
> Notice:  A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.2 Notice:
> To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip Removing intermediate
> container ca89af45e5ee  ---> 97537465f160 Step 7/14 : FROM
> python:3.10-slim-bullseye as final  ---> 06b56278a68d Step 8/14 : RUN
> mkdir /chroma ... Image for service server was built because it did
> not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`. Creating workspace_clickhouse_1
> ...  Creating workspace_clickhouse_1 ... done Creating
> workspace_server_1     ...  Creating worksp
> ace_server_1     ... done

Then on the "Wait for server" step

> Run while ! curl -s http://localhost:8000 > /dev/null; do Waiting for
> server... Waiting for server... Waiting for server... Waiting for
> server... Waiting for server... Waiting for server... ...

Endlessly.

Comment: Apparently, the [service containers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers) i.e. [`jobs.<job_id>.services`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices) seem to be better suited for your use case.

Comment: Regarding your docker action, what does your logs say? Please include your logs in your question.

Comment: Hey Azeem thanks for reaching out, I will look into service containers. I have added relevant logs.

Answer (score 1):

Using a composite action did the trick.
So refactoring the `action.yml` into the following:

```yaml
name: 'ChromaDB'
description: 'Instantiates a chroma database server.'

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Checkout current repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Start server by running docker-compose
      run: docker-compose up -d
      shell: bash

    - name: Wait for server to be ready
      run: |
        while ! curl -s http://localhost:8000 > /dev/null; do
          echo "Waiting for server..."
          sleep 5
        done
      shell: bash
```